# How to programmatically "Select All" items in a list in EditMode()

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have List that I can get into EditMode() and able to manually select items. I want to implement "Select All" and "Deselect All" buttons to allow easier user experience. I have not been able to figure out a way to do that.

What is needed in the Button Action when "Select All" is pressed.

```
struct TestView: View {
@State private var selection = Set<String>()
@State private var isEditMode: EditMode = .inactive
@State private var isEditing = false

let items = [
    "First Item",
    "Second Item",
    "Third Item",
    "Fourth Item"
]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(items, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { name in
            Text(name)
        }
    }
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading)
        {
            Button(action: {
                print("Pressed Select All")
                selection.forEach {item in
                    print(item)
                }
            }) {
                Text("Seleact All")
            }
            .opacity(self.isEditing ? 1 : 0)
        }

        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing)
        {
            Button(action: {
                print("Action button pressed")
                self.isEditing.toggle()
                self.isEditMode = self.isEditing ? .active : .inactive
            }) {
                Text(isEditing ? "Done" : "Actions")
            }

        }
    }
    .environment(\.editMode, self.$isEditMode)
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(self.isEditing)
} }
```

[Example screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XT15.png)

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Use a for loop and loop over your items. I mean - you implemented the "select" button, now you just need to loop over all elements and click the select button programatically with the same code you are using to click one button

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it to work, which is to populate the selection Set directly.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var selection = Set<String>()
    @State private var isEditMode: EditMode = .inactive
    @State private var isEditing = false
    @State private var selectAll = true

    let items = [
        "First Item",
        "Second Item",
        "Third Item",
        "Fourth Item"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(items, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { name in
                Text(name)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading)
                {
                    Button(action: {
                        if self.selectAll
                        {
                            items.forEach {item in
                                selection.insert(item)
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            selection = Set<String>()
                        }
                        self.selectAll.toggle()
                        
                    }) {
                        Text(self.selectAll ? "Seleact All" : "Deselect All")
                    }
                    .opacity(self.isEditing ? 1 : 0)
                }

                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing)
                {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Action button pressed")
                        self.isEditing.toggle()
                        self.isEditMode = self.isEditing ? .active : .inactive
                    }) {
                        Text(isEditing ? "Done" : "Actions")
                    }

                }
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, self.$isEditMode)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(self.isEditing)

        }
    }
}
```

[Example screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNztp.png)